# Apache-Passenger can't start my production rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I'm new to deploying rails applications and for what I read in many sites the Apache/Passenger combo was one of the simplest ones; however I have encountered that Passenger does not want to start my application and displays the following error message when entering the sudo tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error.log
command:

```
Could not spawn process for application /home/test/Documents/sites/depot:
An error occured while starting up the preloader.
Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:406:in
`activate_gem'
...
age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session
because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 6ce15bbe.
Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

I suspect it has to do with my ruby installation, I used rbenv and got the 2.2.3 version but in the error message it was linking to a 2.0.0 version which I have never installed. 
I also suspect that it has something to do with me using this two commands from another guide:

```
 sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

If anybody know how to fix this headache of a problem I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: did you `gem install bundler`?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt Yup, got it installed, same error messages.

Comment: then dimakura is probably on the right path, you need to set your `PassengerDefaultRuby` to the path to the ruby shim in rbenv which is probably under `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby`.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt changed the PassengerDefaultRuby in the passenger.conf file that has indeed changed the ruby version on my error messages to now be 2.2.3 ; however, I now get a "Incomplete response received from application" message in my browser, and within the logs I see: (Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`) I think I'm getting close to solving this (hopefully)

Comment: Now just set the variables in /etc/apache2/envvars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some clues left by @dimakura and @CamdenNarzt I was able to solve this in two stages.

1. As I suspected Passenger was using the wrong version of ruby, to fix this I modified the passenger.conf file located under /etc/apache2/mods-available/ with the output of the **which ruby** command:

Added the line (replace with your own which ruby output)

```
PassengerRuby /home/test/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

2. Restarted apache got a "Incomplete response received from application" error message, checked the logs and noticed that the proper version of ruby was now being used but got an error message:

   "Missing secret_token and secret_key_base for 'production' environment, set these values in config/secrets.yml"

Installed the Figaro gem by following the instructions on this site: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/managing-development-environment-variables-across-multiple-ruby-applications.html then generated a secret key using the command:

```
rake secret
```

Copied the output and opened the config/application.yml file where I entered:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE: [output key from rake secret command]
```

Restarted Apache and it worked!!

Comment: *Don't do that*! You should customize [PassengerRuby](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerruby), not [PassengerDefaultRuby](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerdefaultruby). Leave PassengerDefaultRuby on its original value. Read the documentation to learn the differences between PassengerRuby and PassengerDefaultRuby.

Comment: Thanks @Hongli I have added a PassengerRuby line and left PassengerDefaultRuby with its original value.

Comment: I don't think is a good idea to change `secret_key_base` each time some one open a shell login for the server, and also I don't think is a good idea to any app in the same server shares the `secret_key_base`. Is better if you create the file `config/secrets.yml` and set the value in the file. Also remember to not commit the file to the repository.

Comment: Using [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars) You can store your ENV vars in `.rbenv-vars` in your project root: `echo "SECRET_KEY_BASE=\`rake secret\`" >> /path/to/project/root/.rbenv-vars` then pull it into your config using `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']`.

Comment: There were already secret_key_base values for development and test in my secrets.yml file by default yet I kept on getting that error message.
@KarlWilbur I used Figaro so setup my env. variable for my production database password, do you know if its possible to use Figaro in the same way you are using rbenv-vars?

Comment: Yes, you can use Figaro with rbenv-vars. I use Choices, very similar. It works fine.

Comment: @KarlWilbur I've been looking around and in Figaro's documentation, but I have no clue how to undo the command

     echo "export SECRET_KEY_BASE=`rake secret`" | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/st_env.sh

Then use Figaro to manage those variables.

Comment: You have to edit the `/etc/profile.d/st_env.sh` file and remove what you added. Then move it to `.rbenv-vars`. Then pull the vars in with Figaro.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KarlWilbur I was able to solve this. Will update my answer with the proper way to do it the secure way.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify correct `PassengerDefaultRuby` in your `httpd.conf` file.

My recommendation is to go through the installation of passenger using their official guide:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/

Comment: Thanks for the clue @dimakura I went through the items in the guide, installed some dependency I was supposedly missing, but still with the exact same error =/ Apache2 on ubuntu 14.04 doesn't use httpd.conf anymore, would I add the PassengerDefaultRuby within apache2.conf?

Comment: Do not edit PassengerDefaultRuby. Edit PassengerRuby instead. See my comment to @Zero.